# combinding a list of lists into new lists in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list of lists

```
list_of_lists[['front','stuff'],['back1,'stuff'],['back3','stuff'], ...['back...', 'stuff']]
```

I want to take the front list and append to each of the back lists:

```
['front','stuff','back1','stuff']
['front','stuff','back2','stuff']
['front','stuff','back3','stuff']
 ....
['front','stuff','back..','stuff']
```

I know I can set front = lists_of_lists[0] to get ['front','stuff']

How do I iterate and combine the front and backs, each into their own list?

Comment: Can you give us an expected output? I'm really confused as to what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
[list_of_lists[0] + i for i in list_of_lists[1:]]
```

or if you want to avoid the temporary slice

```
front = list_of_lists[0]
[front + j for i, j in enumerate(list_of_lists) if i]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_lists = [['front','stuff'],['back1','stuff'],['back2','stuff']]

new_list = [my_lists[0] + sublist for sublist in my_lists[1:]]
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[['front', 'stuff', 'back1', 'stuff'], ['front', 'stuff', 'back3', 'stuff']]
```